# How can I permit anonymous access to local user home directory with vsftpd?

Tags: centos, anonymous

I have installed vsftpd and locked local user access to their home directories.

Now I like anonymous to access some user's home directories. I have tried these solutions but they didn't work.

First, I have made a new vsftpd configuration files for anonymous only, and set in that this directive:

```
anon_root=/home/[username]
```

This solution didn't work.

Later I have place this directive in main vsftp configuration file:

```
anonymous_enabled=YES
```

and then set `anon_root` respectively.

Bu this solution didn't work too.

How could I do that?

OS: CentOS 6

Comment: How does it not work ? What error messages are reported? What relevant messages are in your logs ? Is SELinux enabled and are there any relevant log messages ?

Comment: With first solution anonymous couldn't login. With second, I get this error: 550 Failed to change directory.

Comment: Logs. Read the logs. I suspect SELinux being the culprit.

Comment: SELinux is disabled on server

Comment: I checked log files. With second solution anonymous can login but can't change directory to local user home directory

Comment: File ownership probably. Typically a user home directory should not be accessible to others, let alone the default anonymous ftp user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 550 Failed to change directory

With SELinux disabled, this will almost certainly be a simple filesystem permissions issue.
If you look at a typical /home directory entry for a user you will see

```
ls -l /home
drwx------. 40 user user  4096 Mar  5 11:03 user
```

This is normal and as such will deny access to the anonymous user. The anonymous user really shouldn't have access to arbitrary user home directories.